# Project downloaded from GitHub has invisible assets and no references

Tags: unity-game-engine, github

I have a problem with the project downloaded from GitHub. Basically I'm using GitHub as version control of my project and everything works fine. I set it up with LFS and I can commit and push every change I make. The project has a full .gitignore file and .gitattributes file. I've also set Force Text and Visible Meta Files in the Unity project settings. The problem is that if I download the zip of the project from GitHub and I open it, inside all the scenes most of the assets are invisible and Unity gives me a lot of errors such as: "ImportFBX Errors: Couldn't read file <...>", "Could not create asset from ...: File could not be read", "Errors during import of AudioClip ...". The objects are in the hierarchy, but each one has missing reference in different components. I specify that the original project has no issues, only the one downloaded from GitHub. Do you have any ideas of what is causing it?

Comment: And all the assets ARE uploaded to github? Can we see the github repo? Or the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Yes. This is the repo: https://github.com/Pietrofonix/Esame_Programmazione_III_Avanzata

Comment: Sorry it was private, now is public you can see it